# Event parameter overwritten after another event?

Tags: sapui5

In view:

```xml
<List selectionChange=".onSelectionChange">
```

In controller:

```js
onSelectionChange: function (oEvent) {
  console.log(oEvent.sId); // log 1, output "selectionChange"
  MessageBox.warning(Utils.i18n("CHANGE_CONFIRM"), {
    actions: [ Utils.i18n("LEAVE_BTN"), MessageBox.Action.CANCEL ],
    onClose: function (sAction) {
      console.log(oEvent.sId); // log 2, output "closed"
      if (sAction === Utils.i18n("LEAVE_BTN")) {
        this._showDetail(oEvent.getParameter("listItem") || oEvent.getSource(), oEvent.getSource().data("target"));
      }
    }.bind(this)
  });
}
```

Hi, may I ask why `oEvent` changed when `onClose` is triggered? Why can't I store `oEvent` in my scope?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[*Event*](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.base.Event) is a module that implements [*Poolable*](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.base.Poolable), meaning that *Event* has to implement `init` and `reset` which will then be leveraged by its corresponding [*ObjectPool*](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.base.ObjectPool) instance ("oEventPool" internally) to **reuse the existing Event instance** for the next event.

The "next event", in our case, is the `"close"` event which was fired by the dialog. As you could already observe, `oEvent` suddenly doesn't have the ID `"selectionChange"` but `"close"`. This is because the *Event* instance was reset and reused again. And since `oEvent` is just a reference (not a copy), and because JS applies [Call by Object-Sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_sharing), it's "changed".

The API Reference of *ObjectPool* explains what it's doing with the *Event* instance:

> (ObjectPool) maintains a list of free objects of the given type. If [sap.ui.base.ObjectPool.prototype.borrowObject](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.base.ObjectPool/methods/borrowObject) is called, an existing free object is taken from the pool and the [`init`](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/rel-1.52/src/sap.ui.core/src/sap/ui/base/Event.js#L39) method is called on this object.
>
> When no longer needed, any borrowed object should be returned to the pool by calling [#returnObject](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.base.ObjectPool/methods/returnObject). At that point in time, the [`reset`](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/rel-1.52/src/sap.ui.core/src/sap/ui/base/Event.js#L66) method is called on the object and the object is added to the list of free objects.

Currently, the (*oEvent*) object is considered ["no longer needed" when its handler is called](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/rel-1.52/src/sap.ui.core/src/sap/ui/base/EventProvider.js#L226-L239). So the object is already reset right after `onSelectionChange`, and initialized again right before `onClose` is triggered.

UI5 does this so that it doesn't have to create and destroy multiple *Event* instances to improve performance. This is a practice borrowed from the [Object Pool Design Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_pool_pattern) (which is also [often used in game development](https://www.raywenderlich.com/136091/object-pooling-unity)).

---

So, what does it mean for us as application developers? Just don't rely on the event object that is inside a closure. Instead, assign primitive values from the object to separate variables so that we can use them later. E.g.:

```js
onSelectionChange: function(oEvent) {
  const eventId = oEvent.getId(); // === "selectionChange"
  MessageBox.warning(/*...*/, {
    onClose: function() {
      /* oEvent.getId() === suddenly "close" but
         eventId === still "selectionChange"  */
    },
  });
},
```