# How to use `oEvent` when loading fragment asynchronously?

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I'm able to used `oEvent` when using this code:

```js
onPressDialog: function(oEvent) {
    if (!this._oDialog) {
        this._oDialog= sap.ui.xmlfragment("idDialog", "com.Dialog", this);
        this.getView().addDependent(this._oDialog);
    }
    this._oDialog.setBindingContext(oEvent.getSource().getParent().getBindingContext());
    this._oDialog.open();
},
```

However, I'm trying to change it using `Fragment.load` but I'm not able to get the `oEvent` from the function. Any idea?

```js
onPressDialog: function(oEvent) {
    if (!this._oDialog) {
        Fragment.load({ // Fragment required from "sap/ui/core/Fragment"
            id: this.getView().getId(),
            name: "com.Dialog",
            controller: this
        }).then(function(oDialog) {
            this.getView().addDependent(oDialog);
            oDialog.setBindingContext(/*Can't access the right oEvent values here*/);
            oDialog.open();
        }.bind(this));
    }
},
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Event parameter overwritten after change event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47452986/event-parameter-overwritten-after-change-event)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As explained in this [answer from](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47458427/5846045) *[Event parameter overwritten after another event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47452986/event-parameter-overwritten-after-another-event)*, the `oEvent` parameters are completely reset after the event handler (`onPressDialog`) is executed. I.e. after the fragment is fetched asynchronously, the `oEvent` object won't contain the same references / parameter values anymore. Try storing the target reference in a closure variable before creating the fragment, and then use the variable when the promise is finally resolved.

**Given `<Dialog id="myDialog">`** in the fragment definition:

#### Since UI5 1.93

<sup>Using the [API `myController.loadFragment`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.ui.core.mvc.Controller#methods/loadFragment) (Recommended)</sup>

```js
onPressDialog: async function(oEvent) {
  const myEventValue = oEvent.get/*...*/; // to use later without relying on oEvent
  const oDialog = this.byId("myDialog") || await this.loadFragment({ name: "com.Dialog" });
  // ... Do something with myEventValue ...
  oDialog.open();
},
```

#### Since UI5 1.58

<sup>Using the [API `Fragment.load`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.ui.core.Fragment#methods/sap.ui.core.Fragment.load)</sup>

```js
onPressDialog: async function(oEvent) {
  const myEventValue = oEvent.get/*...*/; // to use later without relying on oEvent
  let oDialog = this.byId("myDialog");
  this.getOwnerComponent().runAsOwner(function() {
    if (!oDialog) {
      oDialog = await Fragment.load({ // Fragment required from "sap/ui/core/Fragment"
        id: this.getView().getId(),
        name: "com.Dialog",
        controller: this,
      });
      this.getView().addDependent(oDialog);
    }
    // ... Do something with myEventValue ...
    oDialog.open();
  }.bind(this));
},
```