# Function not seeing the expected parameter from `oEvent` in another event handler

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I have the following function where I call an OData service to validate input and want to clear the source component if the value is not valid.

After calling the service, it does not recognize the `oEvent.getSource().setValue` in the success callback and I'm unable to clear the component.

```js
validateEquipment: function (oEvent) {
    var _this = this;
    var circ7 = _this._oComponent.getModel("LoggedInUser").getData().circ7;
    var equipmentNumber = oEvent.getSource().getValue();
    var equipmentType = "1";
    if (oEvent.getParameter("id").indexOf("containerID") > -1) {
        equipmentType = "2";
    }
    var module = "";
    if (circ7 && equipmentNumber.length === 10) {
        _this._oComponent.getModel("serviceMetaData").read("Equipment_Look(EquipmentType='" + equipmentType + "',EquipmentNumber='" + equipmentNumber + "',Module='" + module + "',Circ7='" + circ7 + "')", {
            success: function (data) {
                if (data && data.ErrorMessage === "") {
                    // ...
                } else if (data) {
                    oEvent.getSource().setValue('');
                    MessageBox.error(data.ErrorMessage);
                }
            },
            // ...
        })
    } else {
        oEvent.getSource().setValue("");
        MessageBox.error("Equipment " + equipmentNumber + " is invalid.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Event parameter overwritten after another event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47452986/event-parameter-overwritten-after-another-event)

Comment: As explained in the above linked answer, *event* is a pooled object. You should store the control reference (`oEvent.getSource()`) **outside** of the `success` callback in a separate variable and use that var later in your handler. Your `oEvent` is being reused by UI5 which is the intended behavior / by design to avoid creating an event object over and over again.

Answer (score 0):

That's a bug in ui5. Events are reused/destroyed somewhere,if another event is happening.

---

Update: apparently it's not a bug. It's a feature.
Ui5 is pooling event objects for no obvious reasons.

```js
validateEquipment: function(oEvent) {
        var _this = this;
        var oSource = oEvent.getSource():
        //_this._oComponent.commonDialog.openBusyDialog();
        var circ7 = _this._oComponent.getModel('LoggedInUser').getData().circ7;
        var equipmentNumber = oSource.getValue();
        var equipmentType = "1";
        if(oEvent.getParameter('id').indexOf("containerID") > -1)
        {
            equipmentType = "2";
        }
        var module = "";
        if (circ7 && equipmentNumber.length === 10) {
            _this._oComponent.getModel("serviceMetaData").read("Equipment_Look(EquipmentType='"+equipmentType+"',EquipmentNumber='"+equipmentNumber+"',Module='"+module+"',Circ7='"+circ7+"')", {
                success: function(data) {
                    if (data && data.ErrorMessage === "") 
                    {
                    } 
                    else if(data) {
                        oSource.setValue('');
                        MessageBox.error(data.ErrorMessage);
                    }
                },
                error: function(error) {
                    MessageBox.error("Failed to load Job Code Data");
                }
            })
        }
        else
        {
            oSource.setValue('');
            MessageBox.error("Equipment " + equipmentNumber + " is invalid.");
        }
    },
```

Comment: Not a bug. By design ;)